# How to smoothly load 200MB data to browser for visualization?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet, data-visualization, kibana

The 200MB data is collected among 300 days, about 600kb daily.

Currently I use
d3.tsv to load one file containing all data,
and then use setTimeout to loop through each day.

But the question is to load 200MB data to client's browser, it can take a few minutes...

How to overcome this problem? Can we use some prefetching and catching technique?

Kibana and Hue can handle gigabytes of data visualization. And both of them seem to use D3 for visualization.

How do they solve the time delay in loading data from the server to client side?

One way I am thinking is to load daily data in every second, and then merge these data to the clients' memory. But how to do the data merge inside of d3.tsv?

```
   mergedData = []

   for (f in filelist) {
     d3.tsv(f, function(error, data)){
      //Following code cannot work as expected
      mergedData = mergedData.concat(data)
     }
   }
```

Because d3.tsv is onload, any global var cannot work inside of it.

Any tricks to work this out?

Comment: Loading and manipulating 200MB of data on the client is either a very bad idea or a very unfortunate necessity... For it to be possible, you would need to know the capabilities of your clients (browser, RAM, processor, etc), and for it to be necessary, you'd need to be doing dynamic manipulation that couldn't be offloaded to the server. Even so, @Cyril's approach of doing the data-wrangling on the server and then supplying aggregated numbers to the client is almost certainly the right approach.

Comment: Why would you want to outsource the data processing to the browser? Even if takes few mins, every user would have to face it. If there is a small memory leak browser will crash along with other pages. During the download the browser will freeze. Browser's are not efficient like databases to quickly process data. So you data processing will be slow.   Javascript is single threaded and if you want to do parallel processing you end up with Web Workers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as kibana is concerned it works on elastic search which operates on millions of records and pulls up the analytic numbers using [aggregates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/search-aggregations.html) and displays it as charts.

Hue works on hadoop.

So in short they get the stats on the bigdata using the backend support of  elasticsearch(In case of kibana) and display the numbers as barchart or other chart using d3.

Hence with large data you should consider taking backend support merge all data get the numbers and let d3 show it up on graph.

Comment: Could you elaborate about what kind of backend support? Do that mean it is only after aggregation and few KB of data will be loaded to d3 and clients' browser?

Comment: When you load your tsv file you will be doing some grouping using d3, and based on that grouped data you will make the bar chart or any other visualization.
What I suggest is that keep the data on the server let some backend code like ruby/java/php work on that large dataset make an aggregation and deliver the concise data to the client browser which uses d3 to make the visualization.